# 403 Forbidden nginx/1.11.9 - Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-4

I kept getting

> 403 Forbidden nginx/1.11.9

I already run : `sudo composer update`

I think I set up proper permissions.

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    149 Feb 24 03:45 .gitignore
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root     12 Feb 24 03:45 .gitattributes
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    146 Feb 24 03:45 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxrwxrwx 15 root root   4096 Feb 24 03:45 app
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    567 Feb 24 03:45 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4096 Feb 24 03:45 bootstrap
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   2452 Feb 24 03:45 artisan
drwxrwxrwx 19 root root   4096 Feb 24 03:45 public
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    519 Feb 24 03:45 server.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root      0 Feb 24 03:45 satisfiable
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   1599 Feb 24 03:45 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Feb 24 03:55 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    992 Feb 24 14:53 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 116004 Feb 24 14:53 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root   4096 Feb 24 14:53 .
drwxrwxrwx 27 root root   4096 Feb 24 14:53 vendor
```

**What else should I look into ?**

---

**ps aux | grep nginx**

```
root     12792  0.0  0.1 148960  1504 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
forge    12793  0.0  0.4 148960  4840 ?        S    Feb24   0:00 nginx: worker process
root     26625  0.0  0.1  12952  1032 pts/0    S+   15:10   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Comment: what is nginx user? `ps aux | grep nginx`

Comment: @FarhadFarahi : Sorry for late reply, I added my results in the post for better readability.

Comment: @FarhadFarahi : Is that mean my `forge` user is wrong ?

Comment: try this: `chown -R forge:forge /path/to/web/root`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had it as

> root /home/forge/distributor-application/laravel;

I updated it to

> root /home/forge/distributor-application/laravel/public;

Final look

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name default;
    root /home/forge/distributor-application/laravel/public;
    ...
}
```

My site is loading back now.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
chown -R forge:forge /path/to/web/root
```

Comment: That is not solved my issue. Thanks for trying. I had a wrong document root set.

Answer (score 0):

if you see this error in laravel 5 and you are in windows check your .yaml file.

```
- map: airbox.aprika
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/airbox/public
```

if lost public end of line then you will see this error.